# Is there a term for operators which modify operands?

Tags: operators, terminology

I believe most operators will not modify their operands.  If I want to ask if an operator is one of those that will alter it's operands, is there a word I can use that means that?  For example:

> Is the bitshift operator a [adjective that means "it will change the operand"]

or

> The '+' operator will not modify a variable, but changing it to '+=' will change the varable on the left, because '+=' is a [need that word again, this time in noun form]

Answer (score 0):

Generally, unary operators and some shorthand operators are those which are used to change the operand.

```
++a;
--a;
a++;
k +=30;
k -=30;
```

etc.

Comment: more like a related tendency than a specific term.